# How to check python anaconda version installed on Windows 10 PC?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a Windows 10 PC with python anaconda installed. The latest anaconda version is v5.0.1

I would like to find out whether the PC has the latest version v5.0.1 installed and whether it is 32-bit/64bit or python 2.7/3.6. How do I do that?

https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: In my case, the disk had enough area. I found that I was changing the default installation location to a different disk on my Ubuntu machine.
when I let the installation run without changing default disk area it ran.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguously formulated. Are you asking about Python or Anaconda? Or Both?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

On the anaconda prompt, do a

- `conda -V` or `conda --version`  to get the conda version.
- `python -V` or `python --version` to get the python version.
- `conda list anaconda$` to get the Anaconda version.
- `conda list` to get the Name, Version, Build & Channel details of all the packages installed (in the current environment).
- `conda info` to get all the current environment details.
- `conda info --envs` To see a list of all your environments

Detailed description [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#), download cheat sheet from [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/cheatsheet.html)

Comment: Here you have more details on how to check the version and update Anaconda: [link](https://medium.com/@mauridb/how-to-check-your-anaconda-version-c092400c9978)

Comment: When I try python --version it says:
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\temp/ipykernel_11684/821963173.py in <module>
----> 1 python -V

NameError: name 'python' is not defined

Answer (score 11):

The folder containing your Anaconda installation contains a subfolder called `conda-meta` with json files for all installed packages, including one for Anaconda itself. Look for `anaconda-<version>-<build>.json`.

My file is called `anaconda-5.0.1-py27hdb50712_1.json`, and at the bottom is more info about the version:

```
"installed_by": "Anaconda2-5.0.1-Windows-x86_64.exe", 
"link": { "source": "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\pkgs\\anaconda-5.0.1-py27hdb50712_1" }, 
"name": "anaconda", 
"platform": "win", 
"subdir": "win-64", 
"url": "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64/anaconda-5.0.1-py27hdb50712_1.tar.bz2", 
"version": "5.0.1"
```

(Slightly edited for brevity.)

The output from `conda -V` is the conda version.

Comment: My file is `anaconda-custom-py36h363777c_0.json`. It doesn't say whether it is v5.0.1 or not. Hard to draw a conclusion.

Comment: Given it says `custom` it's probably not 5.0.1… :)

Comment: And for Miniconda??

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check the python version in a particular conda environment you can also use `conda list python`

Comment: `conda list python -f` will give you only `python` but without the `-f` it will show other matches e.g. `python-dateutil` 
[see docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/list.html)