# Which version of anaconda is installed?

Tags: anaconda, conda

How do I get Anaconda to identify its version on Windows? I have tried:

`anaconda -V`

but this give the "anaconda Command line client" version number, not the version number that would be associated with the installer when you download Anaconda, which, at the moment, is version `2018.12`, and was previously something like `5.3.1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check python anaconda version installed on Windows 10 PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48342098/how-to-check-python-anaconda-version-installed-on-windows-10-pc)

Comment: How does this work for miniconda? If I execute the above the last line (with crucial info) is missing... 

> conda list anaconda
> # packages in environment at /Users/Sarah/miniconda3:
> #
> # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use conda instead:

```
C:\user\dkennetz\Documents>conda list anaconda$
```

This will return only the package named "anaconda" using a regex.

```
# packages in environment at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64:
#
# Name                 Version             Build Channel
anaconda               5.3.0               py36_2
```

Another non-command line way to do this is to go to the folder containing your anaconda installation. This contains a folder called conda-meta with json files for all installed packages, including one for Anaconda itself. Look for the file called `anaconda-<version>-<build>.json`.