# Unable to Import Poppler even after installing in conda

Tags: python, pdftotext, poppler

I am trying to use pdf rendering package Poppler and I found an Anaconda Installation for the same here

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/poppler

I can see the Poppler package installed in my conda env when I do

```
conda <env> list
```

[image]

However when I try to import the package in my code by doing

```
import poppler
```

I get :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'poppler'
```

How do I find if this is the right name of the module if its not the name shown in then conda env list.. I believe the package name is the module name with its own classes and methods.

Why is it saying No module?

Comment: I noticed the same thing. I'm not sure why. (Since you asked me if I had noticed the same thing.)

Comment: So as to install pdftotext (pip install pdftotext), I need to install poppler (conda install -c conda-forge poppler) and I cannot do it either. I receive: (CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED)